# Can broadcast be applied to subarrays/slices of array in julia

Tags: julia, broadcast

I would like to broadcast to subarrays (i.e. broadcast to slices of array). This is useful in GPU programming for example I'd like to have:

```
X,Y,Z = (rand(3,3,3) for _=1:3)
@.[1,2] X = f(2X^2 + 6X^3 - sqrt(X)) + Y*Z
```

where `@.[1,2]` means broadcasting along dim 3, i.e. apply colons to dim 1 and 2 in the expression.

Is there a way to support this "sub-broadcast"?

Edit: add an example

```
julia> a = reshape(1:8, (2,2,2))
2×2×2 Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,3,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8

julia> broadcast(*, a, a)
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1   9
 4  16

[:, :, 2] =
 25  49
 36  64

julia> broadcast(*, a, a, dim=3) # I would like to broadcast the matrix multiplication (batch mode) instead of elementwise multiplication.
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  7  15
 10  22

[:, :, 2] =
 67   91
 78  106
```

Edit 2: I am trying different vectorization methods here https://arrayfire.com/introduction-to-vectorization/ via the ArrayFire.jl package (a wrapper of arrayfire), including vectorization, parallel for-loops, batching, and advanced vectorizations. arrayfire has the gfor (http://arrayfire.org/docs/page_gfor.htm) method to run parallel computations on slices of matrices, and is implemented via broadcast in ArrayFire.jl. Currently, julia's broadcast acts element-wise. I just wonder if it can act "slice-wise" then it can do pure julia 3D and 4D support for Linear Algebra functions (https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/483).

Of course normal nested for loops will get the job done. I am just exited about the broadcast `.` syntax, and wonder if it can be extend.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean, could you give an example with an intended output? Otherwise, yes, using broadcasted operations on slices, or even views, is nothing special, e.g. `X = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; 3 .+ view(X, :, 2)`

Comment: I have added an example, please give comment.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how you get those numbers; care to show the intermediate steps to make it clear what you mean? Also, don't use `a` twice, use `a` and `b` to make it clear what you want acting where. And it's still not clear how a `dim` would be applied to the 'broadcasting' operation per se, rather than either of its arguments. Unless you meant the `dim` should be applied to one of the two arguments (in which case you need to specify which one; matrix multiplication is not symmetric). Come to think of it, it's also not clear what you mean by "broadcasted matrix multiplication".

Comment: I've added some references, hope it makes clear.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you're looking for `mapslices`.

```
mapslices(x->x*x, a, (1,2))
2×2×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
  7  15
 10  22

[:, :, 2] =
 67   91
 78  106
```

> `mapslices(f, A, dims)`
>
> Transform the given dimensions of array A using function f. f is
>   called on each slice of A of the   form A[...,:,...,:,...]. dims is an
>   integer vector specifying where the colons go in this expression.
>   The results are concatenated along the remaining dimensions. For
>   example, if dims is [1,2] and A is   4-dimensional, f is called on
>   A[:,:,i,j] for all i and j.

Use `setdiff` if you want to specify which dimension to concatenate along instead of on which to apply the function.

(If you need a multi-argument version check out this gist https://gist.github.com/alexmorley/e585df0d8d857d7c9e4a5af75df43d00)

Comment: Thanks, mapslices does the job, but it seems if we have `boadcastslices` then the loop-fusion-and-vectorization will make it more efficient: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/blog-post-loop-fusion-and-vectorization-in-julia-0-6/1634

Comment: In most cases (for operations where `a` `<:` `AbstractArray{T,N) where T <: Number`) this will still be fast.